# How to filter old entries with unique id out of SQL query

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql, database

I have a table and a relation

I have maybe 10 Submissions, but when I query the database I only want to get those with a Unique CaseId and the one to return should be the one with the newest Date. Is it possible (And adviceable) to do this in a single query or should I do the filtering in my asp.nets code behind where I fetch the data?

Edit: New images

[image]
[image]

Here you can see that I show many items with the same case id, I only want to show the latest one (Based on date)

This is my current sql query

```
SELECT Submission.Id, Date, center.Name as CenterName, center.Id as CenterId, subject.Name as SubjectName, subject.Id as SubjectId, EmployeeName, Reason, Description, Explanation, Done, ChiefLevel, Action, CaseId 
                    FROM Submission, subject, center
                    WHERE center.Id=CenterId AND subject.Id=SubjectId
                    ORDER BY Date DESC;
```

Comment: A subject can have more then 1 submission. You wan't all submissions that are unique? I'm missing something, can you elaborate a little more.

Comment: `I only want to get those with a Unique CaseId` can u elaborate this?

Comment: Added some more images and text to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My QUERY ended up being this

```
SELECT s.Id, s.Date, c.Name as CenterName, c.Id as CenterId, su.Name as SubjectName, su.Id as SubjectId, s.EmployeeName, s.Reason, s.Description, s.Explanation, s.Done, s.ChiefLevel, s.Action, s.CaseId
                    FROM submission as s
                      INNER JOIN 
                      ( 
                        SELECT CaseId, MAX(Date) AS MaxDateTime 
                          FROM submission 
                        GROUP BY CaseId 
                      ) as groupeds 
                      ON  s.CaseId = groupeds.CaseId 
                      AND s.`Date` = groupeds.MaxDateTime 
                      INNER JOIN
                      (
                        SELECT Id, Name 
                          FROM subject
                      ) as su 
                      ON su.Id=SubjectId
                      INNER JOIN 
                      (
                        SELECT Id, Name 
                          FROM center
                      ) as c 
                      ON c.Id=CenterId;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT caseid 
FROM 
( 
SELECT caseid, max(date) AS max_date 
FROM submission 
GROUP BY caseid 
) a 
JOIN subject t ON a.subjectid=t.id
```